Prod peertube v6.2.1 in server.js Unexpected reserver word await. Failed to start PeerTube daemon
Can't start the PeerTube server at Ubuntu 22
: file:///var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v6.2.1/dist/server.js:2 : await registerOpentelemetryTracing(); : ^^^^^ Sep 01 08:49:42 tube peertube[1306]: SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word Sep 01 08:49:42 tube peertube[1306]:     at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:133:18) Sep 01 08:49:42 tube peertube[1306]:     at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:21) 
node --version
v20.17.0
I completed the installation exactly according to the unscrewing instructions.
I don’t understand why the asynchronous call does not work when the service starts.
